# How do we construct an injective function from the set of algebraic numbers to the set of natural numbers?

Tags: general-topology

How does one construct an injective function $f$ from the set of all algebraic numbers to the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Arthur The set of algebraic numbers is countable.

Answer (score 3):

Typically you don't.  You just prove that the algebraic numbers are countable and quit there.  You start with the proof that the pairs of naturals are countable, iterate that to show that the set of sequences of integers are countable, map sequences to polynomials, and say the set of roots is countable.